# From operational data store to warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, fact-table, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have 3 ODS, so in order to create DWH, do I need a DWH for each ODSs, or the DWH select the tables from any of the ODSs?

Comment: Can you please share details of each of your ODS ?

Answer (score 1):

The design of a DWH is based on your reporting requirements. The number and locations of any data sources is entirely irrelevant.

Also, please can you explain what you mean by the phrase "the DWH select Dim table for any of the ODSs"? It doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: I meant to say: he DWH select the tables from any of the ODSs?